# Neo4j Log File too Big

Tags: neo4j, cypher, nosql

I am running Neo4j and my /log/neo4j.log file is growing to 20Gb. Can somebody write the exact configuration parameter I need to put in my neo4j.conf file to keep it at 20MB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are running neo4j 3.0 or greater.

You need to change the **neo4j.conf** file. It can be found at,

> /etc/neo4j/neo4j.conf

In the Logging Configuration section, you will find several sections detailing which logs you are keeping.

Two values that need to be changed for each section you are keeping.

Example:

> dbms.logs.gc.rotation.keep_number=5
>
> dbms.logs.gc.rotation.size=20m

You could keep two logs each at 10m size and rotate between them.

These two values need to be changed for each log type you are keeping.
Http, GC, Debug, Query.

Comment: Are all of the logs stored in the same neo4j.log file?

Comment: Hi there Anomaly. It looks like you're adding some good answers recently, but we would rather answer posts did not contain requests for upvotes/accepts. We think that good answers will attract these kind of feedbacks automatically. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback halfer. I'll refrain from doing it.

Comment: @sepehr-sobhani There are multiple log files. You will need to enable the types you want from the neo4j.conf file. There will be log files such as debug.log, neo4j.log,  query.log and so on depending on which logging options you have enabled from the conf file.

The logs can be found at /var/log/neo4j/